# Can't native debug

Tags: android, android-ndk, adt, android-debug

I was able to use the native debug functionality until recently.  I've been coding in java and went back to the native code but now I can't native debug.  It will run and with the previously working debug config but I get a Null Pointer error on launch right when it would be attaching:

> 'Launching [debug config]' has encountered a problem.
>
> An internal error occurred during 'Launching [debug config]'.
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException

The app will run on the device, but won't hit breakpoints.  Anyone seen this, it's driving me nuts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this was due to the manifest "debuggable" being set to false.  When you don't run native it tells you exactly that.  With native, you get the absolutely useless error.  I'll put in an enhancement request.